# one tasks/command in jekins master another task/command in jenkins slaves

Tags: jenkins

I would like to run one command in jenkins master another command in jenkins slave. How to do this one jenkins job? if not possible in one jenkins job, then how to call second job using execute shell in the first job?

Answer (score 1):

You can manage that with the [Conditional Step plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin).

Just add a build step like below:

[image]